# library for server side (c/c++) xmlrpc

Tags: c++, c, xml-rpc

I want to implement support of the XMLRPC protocol for my server that is written in C and C++ and now looking for the most widely adopted xmlrpc library. License is not an issue, GPL would be fine. What would you suggest ? Is there any defacto standard xmlrpc C library for such a purpose ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The de facto standard would imo be this one: http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/ and it supports both C and C++ and it even has its own embedded http daemon for servicing the http requests ...

edit: and it's available under a BSD-style license, so it allows you to boldly go where GPL didn't allow you to go before ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options:

- [XML-RPC for C and C++](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/)

I've never used this one.

- [GSoap](http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/)

I have used this.  It's industrial strength and does what it says on the tin.